# "Security Settings prevented XYZ Software from Loading" windows has not option to close

Tags: macos, security, wacom

I am trying to install a software for a graphical tablet called Wacom. On restarting my laptop after installing its device drivers, I see a warning on my desktop saying "Security Settings prevented Wacom System Software from Loading".
The only action possible is to click 'try again'. There is no option to close the window.

Why has it hijacked my screen and how can I close it?

OS: Big Sur 11.0.1

[image]

Comment: What version of macOS are you running?  Please update with an [edit] to your question.  .

Comment: You should also not still be on 11.0.1. Latest Big Sur is 11.7.3, which will have had very many bugs & security issues fixed since the initial release, over two years ago.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a normal macOS prompt. This is from your Wacom software. Follow the instructions to be able to use the software (or uninstall the software if you do not wish to use it).

Answer (score 0):

I also got into this trouble last week.

**Make sure you toggle 2 security items for Wacom.
So, under Privacy & Security:

1. Accessibility
2. Input Monitoring**

That's it!

Check my screenshots here as well>>
[image: Screenshot of Privacy & Security settings, Macbook Pro 16" 2021]

[image: Screenshot of Accessibility settings]

[image: Screenshot of Input Monitoring settings]

(Long story: That same nag dialog box appeared on mine when I neglected "Input Monitoring" option.
Had to restart twice when I kept losing ability to use any mouse or keyboard, even touchpad [i.e. input devices])